# Getting PostgreSQL set up on Ubuntu bash running on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently installed and set-up rails on an Ubuntu bash running on Windows as a Linux subsystem. I was able to get rails up and going without a problem and create a new rails application on my Windows C:/ drive. I tried downloading PSQL directly from the [postgresql.org/downloads/windows](http://postgresql.org/downloads/windows) website but had some issues so I canceled, then followed the Installing PostgresQL section of [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@helenflam/how-to-change-your-rails-app-database-from-sqlite-to-postgresql-before-deploying-to-heroku-ae2acc25c7ac). The only issue is that the previous download which was canceled was set to listen to the default Port 5432, and it appears to have kept the port occupied because the second installation said it had to use Port 5433.

EDIT: It appears that the original PSQL had been successfully installed as it appeared in my program list, I was able to uninstall it but did get an error warning that the data folder was not removed. After uninstalling and having only one installed copy of PSQL, I still get the same error when running the below `sudo service postgresql start`.

EDIT EDIT: I uninstalled both versions of PSQL completely and re-installed the version in the linked tutorial and it got rid of the second error I was having. However, my 'pg' gem is still not bundle installing.

Once that was complete, I tried switching over my existing rails application to postgresql. I updated the database.yml file and added the 'pg' gem to my Gemfile. I cannot, however, bundle install. When I try, I get this error:

```
Fetching pg 1.0.0
Installing pg 1.0.0 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/<user_profile>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pg-1.0.0/ext
/home/<user_profile>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180717-4727-vex5p2.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a
client-side application.
You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a
client-side application.
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/<user_profile>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-pg
        --without-pg
        --enable-windows-cross
        --disable-windows-cross
        --with-pg-config
        --without-pg-config
        --with-pg_config
        --without-pg_config
        --with-pg-dir
        --without-pg-dir
        --with-pg-include
        --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
        --with-pg-lib
        --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/<user_profile>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0-static/pg-1.0.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/<user_profile>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/pg-1.0.0 for
inspection.
Results logged to
/home/<user_profile>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0-static/pg-1.0.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (1.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '1.0.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  pg
```

EDIT: Below is solved, refer to second edit above.

Similarly, when I try to start postgresql from the command line using `sudo service postgresql start`, I get the following:

```
$ sudo service postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.5 database server                                                                            * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2018-07-17 14:59:26 DST [4858-1] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Permission denied
2018-07-17 14:59:26 DST [4858-2] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5433? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2018-07-17 14:59:26 DST [4858-3] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
2018-07-17 14:59:26 DST [4858-4] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
```

Does anybody know what is going wrong with the installation of PostgresQL in my environment and how I can get it successfully running on my Ubuntu shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution to these problems.

Issue #1 - 'pg' gem not installing
Execute the following in bash:

1. sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
2. gem install pg
3. bundle install

Issue #2 - postgresql cannot start without crashing

Uninstall all versions on PSQL on computer and reinstall one. The failed installation and the second version were sharing their data folder and caused errors with the installation I was using.